# JavaScript append Rails erb code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I got a complicated `select` block which was written by rails `erb`, but now I need to rewrite it into jQuery using `append`.

The select block is like this

```
<select id="mission_reward" name="mission_reward" class="select_reward">
  <option value="0"><%=t('mission.create_panel.no_reward')%></option>
  <% @monsters.each do |monster|%>
    <option data-img-src="<%=monster.url%>"
            data-cost='<%=monster.need_q_point%>'
            value="<%=monster.id%>">
      <%= monster.name %>
    </option>
  <% end%>
</select>
```

I've written some code following

**html**

```
<div class='select_block'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('select_block').append(AppendReward());
  });
</script>
```

**js**

```
function AppendReward(){
  return
  "<select id=\"mission_reward\" name=\"mission_reward\" class=\"select_reward\"> \
    <option value="0"><%=t('mission.create_panel.no_reward')%></option> \
    <% @monsters.each do |monster|%> \
      <option data-img-src="<%=monster.url%>" \
            data-cost='<%=monster.need_q_point%>' \
            value=\"<%=monster.id%>\"> \
        <%= monster.name %> \
      </option> \
    <% end%> \
  </select>"
}
```

But it seems to fail, I am not familiar with JavaScript, is it wrong with the syntax?

Comment: What is `select_block`? Can you show more of it?

Comment: `select_block` is in the `html` file.
`select_block` is the target `div` where I need to append block

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

use the below

```
<div class='select_block' id = "select_block"></div>
```

In  Jquery , write the below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#select_block').append(AppendReward());  
});
```

instead of

```
  $(function() {
    $('select_block').append(AppendReward());
  });
```